# How to backup Mac to external hard drive in recovery mode? "No mountable file systems"?

Tags: backup, upgrade, high-sierra

I upgraded my mac to High Sierra **without** backing up my data. Then my Mac wouldn’t login, it gives me a black screen then it restarts.

So I decided to reinstall the software, but first I need to back up my data. I’ve been trying since last night. I put Mac in recovery mode, then I created a “compressed” disc image to put it on an external hard drive. I wanted to make sure I can open it before I reinstall and in the process lose all the data. I put it on a friend's Mac, and it keeps saying “no mountable file systems” and the dmg won’t open. The dmg file has a size of 500 GB.

Is there any other way to backup my data, given that I can't login into my Mac after the High Sierra install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking to back up **data** rather than the entire drive, as your OS image is probably faulty.

That being the case, you may be able to start up in **Target Disk Mode**, and then you can browse the files and copy them to another disk as if the HDD in the Mac was just an external drive. There are a couple caveats to this though:

- Make sure your Mac is compatible - Given that you are updating to Sierra it is likely that it is.
- You will need another Mac to connect the dead one to.
- You need a USB-C, Thunderbolt 3, Firewire or Thunderbolt 2 Cable

Connect the computers up, and when starting the broken machine, immediately press and hold 'T'.

All being well it will appear as a disk on the other Mac. You should be able to offload your data from here.

Here is some more info, including compatibility lists: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201462)

Comment: Thank you ! I followed the instructions, and I used a thunderbolt cable. The target Mac is in disc target mode, but the host Mac is not showing the target Mac. It showed up for less than a minute, then it disappeared. Is there away to fix this ?

Comment: I tried it again by turning on the target Mac after turning on the host Mac, and it worked. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! If you could mark my answer as solving your problem that would be great. :)

Comment: I marked the green check button